# Realm API Bridge documentation

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

We are trying to build a thing that synchronises JSON into RealmPlatform on the server side, and as far as we looked there is no documentation for it other then:
`Easily connect your mobile apps to existing systems and APIs.`

Is there a way we can inspect, we want to PUT items into it.

Answer (score 1):

We offer a Node.js SDK in the enterprise edition that can be used server-side to do two things:

1. Open synchronized Realms and interact with them using the same API as our [realm-js SDK](https://github.com/realm/realm-js) for React Native uses today (the Node.js SDK is based on the same code base, just has additional closed-source code to handle synchronized Realms)
2. There are additional APIs in the Node.js SDK not found in the current [realm-js SDK](https://github.com/realm/realm-js) that support adding a listener across 1 or more Realms. This supports building server-side logic that reacts to incoming data from the clients. For example, this could be used as an API bridge to pass incoming data into internal APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Things have improved slightly since then.

I assume you are talking about [API bridging](https://realm.io/pricing/) which as shown is only available for the Professional/Enterprise versions.

Further digging in the documentation shows that it is batched under [Enabling Professional and Enterprise APIs](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/pe-ee/#enabling-professional-and-enterprise-apis), i.e. Event Handling, Data Access and Data Connector, within that is a link to a Demo app which is rather unhelpful.

Eventually I stumbled across this https://realm.io/solutions/api-mobilization/ which has a paragraph about "How It All Works" but no documentation. I guess they expect you to "Grok" the code/demo to understand how it works, but then I suppose if you are willing to pay at least $1500/month, they will probably send you better documentation.